# What is the diference between consumable Product and Non-consumable product in In-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am started integrating Android In-app Billing V3 in my App. I read all android developer documents. Still I have following doubts?

- What is the diference between consumable Product and Non-consumable product?
- Why i need to consume a product after purchasing it?
- if i want to sell a mobile device,shall i need add each mobile in Developer console product list? or adding one mobile is enough and buy the same product with different mobile IMEI?
- If all products sold in my developer console,then shall i want to add new products?
- What is the maximum number of products I can add in each application in  Developer console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- What is the diference between consumable Product and Non-consumable product?
  Consumable products can be purchased multiple time by same user. but Non-consumable can be purchased only once.
- Why i need to consume a product after purchasing it?
  It depends on your app idea. Ex:- If you are developing a game and want to add some special power for limited period of time you can do it with consumable products.
- if i want to sell a mobile device,shall i need add each mobile in Developer console product list? or adding one mobile is enough and buy the same product with different mobile IMEI?
  Please clear me if I am wrong are you planning to sell mobile? If yes then with in-App Purchase you can not sell any physical items.
- If all products sold in my developer console,then shall i want to add new products?
  No,in developer console the product list is just like menu card of hotel which shows all available products of that app.
- What is the maximum number of products I can add in each application in Developer console.
  Practically no limits. From in-App 3 in response google will send 999 product ids in one response if you have more items you can fetch in second request.

I think you are very new to in-app please see [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html) of in-app.

Comment: My scenario is,A user have multiple products,each product should have separate subscription.Then how to maintain each user,each product subscription.Add one subscription product in developer console and purchase same subscription in for all products in same user? is it possible?

Comment: Your requirement is little bit confusing for me. You want multiple products for a user but want to add one subscription only in developer console. Am I right? Do you want one time purchase or subscription both are different? You can add multiple products in developer console and each product should be unique. A user can purchase multiple products in your app.

Comment: yes,I want multiple products for a user but want to add one subscription only in developer console. If i do like ,Google play will take care of each products subscription automatically?

Comment: No, you have to add subscription price and time duration for each product. This is as simple as creating a mailid. You have to fill 4-5 text-box and done rest google will take care.